# Creating safe overlapping/union fields in structs

Tags: memory, rust, unions

In C++, I can create structures like these:

```
union Vector4
{
    struct { float x, y, z, w; };
    float data[4];
};
```

so I can easily access the data as fields or as an contiguous array. Alternatively, I can just create a pointer to the first field `x` and read from the pointer as an contiguous array.

I know that there are enums, but I can't pay for the additional overhead. I also know I can create unions in Rust, but they require me to litter my code with `unsafe` where ever I'm accessing them. Which I feel I shouldn't have to since the code is not unsafe as the underlying data is always represented as floats (and I need the C-layout `#[repr(C)]` so the compiler won't throw around the order of the fields).

How would I implement this in Rust so that I can access the fields by name but also have easy and safe access to the whole struct's contiguous memory? If this is not possible, is there a way so I can safely take a slice of a struct?

Comment: Would storing it as an array and having methods to access the fields by name work?

Comment: I'm pretty positive that any decent C++ compiler would optimize something like `float getX() { return data[0]; }` to be exactly as efficient as a union, and this probably applies to Rust

Comment: @apetranzilla Yes, that's an option. I prefer the C++ version of unions though as the getters and setters gets quite clustered, especially when they're just an abstraction over a primitive. The union also feels more explicit on the use-case. But otherwise, that's the best alternative

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Unfortunately I don't think there's really a better way. Rust is very explicit about what needs to be marked `unsafe`, and since unions could be used to construct illegal bit patterns and cause UB, you always need to use `unsafe` to access their fields. If the type is reasonably simple, you could create two separate structs with the same representation and a method to convert between the two, which should be optimized out by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a safe union. Personally, I would argue that transmuting between fixed sized arrays of integer types should be considered safe, but at the moment there are no exceptions.

That being said, here is my totally 100% not a union `Vector4`. As you can see, `Deref` works to hide the unsafe code and makes it so you can treat `Vector4` as either a struct or an array based on the context it is used in. The transmute also isn't ideal, but I feel like I can justify it in this case. If you choose to do something like this, then you may also want to implement `DerefMut` as well.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

// I'm not sure if the repr(C) is needed in this case, but I added it just in case.
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Vector4<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub z: T,
    pub w: T,
}

impl<T> Deref for Vector4<T>
where
    T: Copy + Sized,
{
    type Target = [T; 4];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        use std::mem::transmute;
        unsafe { transmute(self) }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = Vector4{
        x: 37,
        y: 21,
        z: 83,
        w: 94,
    };

    println!("{:?}", &a[..]);
    // Output: [37, 21, 83, 94]
}
```

Comment: `repr(C)` is indeed required in this case: the default representation does not guarantee a layout that would match `[f32; 4]`, as defined [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html).

Comment: Personally I would not use `Deref` for this but `AsRef<[T; 4]>`, because `Vector4` is not semantically a smart pointer and it seems like the OP wants to maintain some separation between the two "views" of the data (but that is ultimately a subjective decision).

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, although I'm concern that it looks like `std::mem::transmute` does a copy, so you're not accessing the actual underlying data but returning a copy with a new representation.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman in this case it's not the `Vector4` that's being transmuted, but rather the `&Vector4` - the reference is being copied, not the underlying data. And in practice neither case would do any copying anyways, the compiler would optimize it out since the types have the same exact layout.

Comment: I don't think `std::mem::transmute` should be copying anything. We already have `std::mem::transmute_copy` to do that.

Comment: I see, then this might work. I have to test it a bit more but it sounds promising!

Comment: @Ted You don't technically need `transmute` for this, since pointer casting is sufficient: ` unsafe { &*(self as *const _ as *const _) }`